# Можно ли залить версию сайта с другим языком на поддомен через Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, поддомены, wordpress-multisite

*Здравствуйте!* Есть **Wordpress-multisite**. На хосте есть поддомен, который подсоеденен к WP (в админке WP теперь 2 сайта). Вопрос: **Можно ли залить переведенный контент на поддомен через WP? Или это делается через хост?**

Comment: Непонятно - ты хочешь разделить сайты и избавиться от мультисайтовости или в чем проблема? Что значит "выгрузить версию" и как это связано с "залить контент"?

Comment: SeVlad, возможно я не правильно выразился. Я из простого WP-сайта сделал мульти сайт, зарегал на хосте поддомен и подсоединил к сайту. Когда я захожу в админке WP на второй сайт - вижу белый экран(оно и понятно, поддомен же пустой). Я хотел узнать можно ли через Wordpress залить переведенные данные на поддомен или это можно только через хост и ftp?

Comment: Понятней не стало, а наоборот, появилось ещё больше вопросов.. Но ответ на последний вопрос - всё и всегда "заливается" только через ВП,